# Remove a portion of HTML text using Python

Tags: python, html

I have a very long HTML text of the following structure:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph 1 Lorem ipsum dolor... long text... </p>
        <p>Paragraph 2 Lorem ipsum dolor... long text... </p>
        <p>Paragraph 3 Lorem ipsum dolor... long text... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, let's say I want to trim the HTML text to just 1000 characters, but I still want the HTML to be valid, that is, close the tags whose closing tags were removed. What can I do to correct the trimmed HTML text using Python? Note that the HTML is not always structured as above.

I need this for an email campaign wherein a preview of the blog is sent but the recipient needs to visit the blog's URL to see the complete article.

Comment: Are you using any framework? if so, which one?

Comment: I can have Django or Odoo for this, though I'm actually using Odoo in this case. I can get rendered HTML body from my template but I need to trim it first, and then send the modified HTML to my mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about BeautifulSoup? (python-bs4)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = """<div>
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph 1 Lorem ipsum dolor... long text... </p>
        <p>Paragraph 2 Lorem ipsum dolor... long text... </p>
        <p>Paragraph 3 Lorem ipsum dolor... long text... </p>
    </div>
</div>"""

test_html = test_html[0:50]
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

.prettify() should close the tags automatically.

Comment: As for now, this is the most viable solution presented. But if this can be down by using a simple non-module code, it is maybe better.

Answer (score 0):

I can show an example.
If it looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>Long text...</p>
  <p>Longer text to be trimmed</p>
</div>
```

And you have a Python code like:

```
def TrimHTML(HtmlString):
    result = []
    newlinesremaining = 2 # or some other value of your choice
    foundlastpart = False
    for x in list(HtmlString): # being HtmlString the html to be trimmed
        if not newlinesremaining < 1:
            if x == '\n':
                newlinesremaining -= 1
            result.append(x)
        elif foundlastpart == False:
            if x == \n:
                newlinesremaining = float('inf')
                foundlastpart == True
        return result.join('')
```

and you run that code inputting the example HTML above in the function, then the function returns:

```html
<div>
  <p>Long text...</p>
</div>
```

For some probably odd reason I couldn't test it in the short time window that I have before work.

Comment: This assumes that each line is one line of valid HTML with properly closed tags. Also, what if I remove all line breaks or minify the HTML?

Comment: According to official documentation, it is not recommended to do so, so it might be uncommon to find a minified HTML. Either way I ain't much good at such scripts.